# Verify the given linear approximation and determine the values of x for which it is accurate within 0.1

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, approximation

> Verify the given linear approximation at $a=0$. Then determine the values of x for which the linear approximation is accurate within 0.1: $$ln(1 + x) ≈ x $$

The official method that was used to calculate a question similar to this was to use this formula:

$$ |f(x) - L(x)| < 0.1 $$

for example, in this case, it would be:

$$|ln(1 + x) - x| < 0.1 $$

My first question is, how do you solve for x algebraically in the equation above?

My second question is why isn't this the equation?

$$ |f'(x) - L(x)| < 0.1 $$

Logically I think the equation above makes more sense because you want to compare the approximation of the tangent line (L(x)) with the actual tangent line (f'x).

Comment: Where did the $a$ in $f'(a)$ go?

Comment: @Gae.S. You are right. The x in the denominator should be a 0 so I guess L(x) does equal x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the inequality you would be solving would be

$$|x-\ln(1+x)|<0.1$$

because you're trying to find the difference between your approximation $x$ and the function $\ln(1+x)$ itself.

WolframAlpha gives the following solution to six decimal places:

$$-0.383183<x<0.516221$$

Comment: That is in fact, the correct answer, but why would the equation be $L(x) - f(x) < 0.1$ rather than $L(x) - f'(x) < 0.1$? Isn't the question asking to compare the linear approximation with the actual slope?

Comment: @RudyGoburt Linear approximations approximate values of a **function** near a certain point as opposed to the value of the function's derivative. When you say that $\ln (1+x) \approx x$ at $a=0$, what you're saying is that given a value $b$ that is close to $a$, $\ln(1+b) \approx b$. $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ is the function that you're working with, and $L(x)=x$ is its approximation near $0$. Hopefully this helps; I would happy to provide more clarification if necessary.

Comment: Is the question asking for which part of the linear approximation's SLOPE is within 0.1 or a POINT on the line itself?

Comment: @RudyGoburt No. What it's asking is this: which values of $x$ are there such that $x$ (the approximation) is within $0.1$ of $\ln(1+x)$ (the actual function)?